# C++ error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'input >> Group1->Entrepreneur::Item'|

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error and have searched for a good 4-6 hour to try and get a solution but none of my searches yielded any results in my particular situation so here is my main.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Entrepreneur.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool operator >(const Entrepreneur & Group1,const Entrepreneur & Group2)
{
    if((Group1.Points > Group2.Points || Group1.Points == Group2.Points) && Group1.Profit > Group2.Profit )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    };
};

ostream &operator<<( ostream &output,const Entrepreneur &Group1)
{
 output <<"\nItem : " << Group1.Item << "\nNr : " << Group1.Nr << "\nDonation : R" << Group1.Donation << "\nStart up amount : R" << Group1.StartUpAmt << "\nExpenses : R" << Group1.Expenses <<"\nPoints : " << Group1.Points << "\nSold : " << Group1.Sold << endl;;
 return output;
};

    istream &operator>>( istream  &input,const Entrepreneur & Group1)
{
    cout << "Enter Items to be sold,Donation amount,number of members & startup amount. Seperated by a space." << endl;

    input >> Group1.Item >> Group1.Donation >> Group1.Nr >> Group1.StartUpAmt;
    return input;
};

int main()
{


    return 0;
};
```

and here is my header file.

```
#ifndef ENTREPRENEUR_H_INCLUDED
#define ENTREPRENEUR_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Entrepreneur{
    private:
        string Item;
        int Nr;
        double Donation;
        double StartUpAmt;
        double Expenses;
        double Income;
        double Profit;
        int Points;
        bool Sold;
    public:
        Entrepreneur(){
            Item = "Not Decided";
            Nr = 1;
            Donation = 0;
            StartUpAmt = 0;
            Expenses = 0;
            Income = 0;
            Profit = 0;
            Points = 0;
            Sold = 0;
        };
        void CreatGroup(string iItem,int iNr,double iDonation,double iStartUpAmt){
            Item = iItem;
            Nr = iNr;
            Donation = iDonation;
            StartUpAmt = iStartUpAmt;
        };
        void DisplayGroup(){
            cout << "\nItem : " << Item << "\nNr : " << Nr << "\nDonation : R" << Donation << "\nStart up amount : R" << StartUpAmt << "\nExpenses : R" << Expenses << "\nIncome : R" << Income << "\nProfit : R" << Profit << "\nPoints : " << Points << "\nSold : " << Sold << endl;
        };
        void set_info(double iExpenses,double iIncome,bool iSold){
            Expenses = iExpenses;
            Income = iIncome;
            Sold = iSold;
        };
        void calc_profit(double iDonation,double iStartUpAmt,double iExpenses,double iIncome){
            Donation = iDonation;
            StartUpAmt = iStartUpAmt;
            Expenses = iExpenses;
            Income = iIncome;

            Profit = Income + (StartUpAmt + Donation) - Expenses;
        };
        void update_points(){
            Points = 0;

            if(Nr < 3)
            {
                Points ++;
            }
            else
            {
                Points + 2;
            }
            if(Donation == 0)
            {
                Points ++;
            }
            if(Sold == 1)
            {
                Points ++;
            }
        };
        void Display(){
            cout << "Congratulations to all groups that partook in the challenge !" << endl;
        };

        friend bool operator >(const Entrepreneur & Group1,const Entrepreneur & Group2);
        friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output,const Entrepreneur & Group1);
        friend istream &operator>>( istream  &input,const Entrepreneur & Group1);


};

#endif // ENTREPRENEUR_H_INCLUDED
```

So the error comes from the friend member that overloads the operator>> 
In Entrepreneur class in Entrepreneur.h

```
friend istream &operator>>( istream  &input,const Entrepreneur & Group1);
```

In main.cpp:

```
istream &operator>>( istream  &input,const Entrepreneur & Group1)
{
    cout << "Enter Items to be sold,Donation amount,number of members & startup amount. Seperated by a space." << endl;

    input >> Group1.Item >> Group1.Donation >> Group1.Nr >> Group1.StartUpAmt;
    return input;
};
```

I have hit a wall here normally 10min on google and I would have fixed it but this one has got the better of me. PS the program is not finished found this when i started testing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read into a `const` object

```
istream &operator>>(istream  &input, const Entrepreneur & Group1)
```

This is why your

```
input >> Group1.Item >> Group1.Donation >> Group1.Nr >> Group1.StartUpAmt;
```

does not compile. Get rid of the `const` in the parameter declaration.

An unrelated issue

```
Points + 2;
```

This is no-op statement.

Comment: Thanks I tried to remove the const but then I get an error because Item variable in class Entrepreneur is private, even though its a friend function trying to access it. And thanks on the second point

Comment: Thanks it worked I just forgot to remove the cont from the friend function in the header file again thanks very much